# PyQt Window No Show

Tags: python, pyqt

Upon calling the show method on simple the simple window does not show. Why doesn't my Simple window show. :(

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        simple = Simple()

        button = QtGui.QPushButton("Button", self)
        button.clicked.connect(simple.show)
        self.show()


class Simple(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Simple, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(300, 250, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle("Simple Widget")


if __name__ =="__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = Widget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Please Help!

Comment: where have you called show for `Simple` widget ?

Comment: When the button is clicked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with your code is that, `simple` in `__init__` method of class `Widget` is a local variable, so as soon as the `__init__` method finishes execution, the `simple` object is destroyed by the python *Garbage Collector*, thus the window does not appear because the object does not exist in the memory. To solve your problem, just add `self` at the starting of the `simple` variable to make it member variable.

```
...
self.simple = Simple()
button = QtGui.QPushButton("Button", self)
button.clicked.connect(self.simple.show)
...
```