# PyQt5 Switch between two Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I want to create an app that switches between two Window:

```
import sys
from Model.Model import *

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

model = Model()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setWindowTitle("My Awesome App")

        label = QLabel("This is a PyQt5 window!")

        label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.setCentralWidget(label)

class LoginWindow(QMainWindow):
    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        self.close()

        main = MainWindow()
        main.show()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setWindowTitle("My Awesome App")

        btn = QPushButton("Start")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        layout.addWidget(btn)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = LoginWindow()
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

The problem is that when I click the button the LoginWindow disappears but the MainWindow did not appear, any idea what is the problem?

Comment: I think because you invoke `self.close()` first, you can try putting it after `main.show()`. I think `self.close()` destroys the window so the rest of the code do not run.

Comment: @albusSimba No. The problem is that `main` is a local variable, and as soon as `on_click()` returns it is destroyed by the garbage collector. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23880530/pyqt-window-no-show

Comment: I see so the quick fix is to create the object `main = MainWindow()` after `window = LoginWindow()`

Comment: @albusSimba Yes and no. It depends on many things: for example, if the main window has a lot of things to do in its `__init__` and the user cancels the login, there's no need to do the loading before that. In this cases it might be better to find an alternate logic that waits for the login window to return and *then* creates the main window *if* the login is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have main as a variable of the instance, because when you're declaring it locally it does not exist after you exit the function.

So, in `__init__`:

```py
self.main = MainWindow()
```

And in `on_click`:

```py
self.main.show()

self.close()
```